# wpf ComboBox and how to get values out of Items

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a ComboBox in editable mode in my wpf application and I would like to know what would be the best way to get its Items string values for use. I tried moviecomboBox.Items.CurrentItem.ToString(), but it doesn't work.

**Edit:** Here is a part of my xaml code:

```
<ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Movie" Grid.Column="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="9,4,0,4" Name="movieComboBox" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" IsEditable="True">
            <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
        </ComboBox>
```

And I would like to be able to use the Items values in xaml.cs file.

Comment: Can u give some example code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers the solution was in the end as simple as movieComboBox.Text.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `SelectedItem` property:

```
moviecomboBox.SelectedItem != null ? moviecomboBox.SelectedItem.ToString() : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying using SelectedItem instead of CurrentItem.

```
moviecomboBox.Items.SelectedItem.ToString()
```